# how to make fixed static option field show on the basis of select of dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html

what i am trying to my below code two dropdown field is there one is rat and another is cat and when i am select cat then four text field is show and when i select then two text field is show .

but in my code what happen is there and i try to make when i am select cat then four field is show with level and when i select rat then two filed is show with level.

what i am trying to do is when i am select rat then two filed is show without any space .

but in my code when i am select rat then two fied is show but is come in space how can we do that without space is show.

is there any help check my code below.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".carm3").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() === 'other'){ 
            jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').show();   
        } else {
            jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').hide(); 
        }
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".carm3").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() === 'r'){ 
            jQuery('input[name=oth]').show();   
        } else {
            jQuery('input[name=oth]').hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="carm3" name="interest">
   <option value="">select</option>
    
    <option value="other">cat</option>
    <option value="r">Rat</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="other_interest" style="display:none" /><br><br>
<input type="text" name="other_interest" style="display:none" /><br><br>
<input type="text" name="other_interest" style="display:none" /><br><br>
<input type="text" name="other_interest" style="display:none" /><br><br>
 <input type="text" name="other_interest" style="display:none" />
 
 <input type="text" name="oth" style="display:none" /><br><br>
 <input type="text" name="oth" style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when `display: none`, the `<br>` tags still remain, since only `<input>` are hidden.

Wrap your inputs in `<div>`, breaking them into *groups*, like my html, and in the *jquery* code, refer not to `<input>` tags, but divs with `.cats` and `.rat` claases.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".carm3").change(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() === "other") {
            jQuery(".cat").show();
            jQuery(".rat").hide();
        } else if (jQuery(this).val() === "r") {
            jQuery(".rat").show();
            jQuery(".cat").hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(".rat").hide();
            jQuery(".cat").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="carm3" name="interest">
    <option value="">select</option>

    <option value="other">cat</option>
    <option value="r">Rat</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />

<div class="cat" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="other_interest" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="other_interest" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="other_interest" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="other_interest" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="other_interest" />
</div>

<div class="rat" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="oth" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="oth" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<div id='cat'>
<input type="text" name="other_interest" />
<input type="text" name="other_interest" />
<input type="text" name="other_interest"  />
<input type="text" name="other_interest" />
 <input type="text" name="other_interest" />
 
 </div>
<div id='rat'> 
<input type="text" name="oth" />
 <input type="text" name="oth" />
</div>
```

and then use their corresponding div to toggle

```
$('.carm3').onChange(function(e) {
$('#cat').hide();
$('#rat').hide();
if(this.value == 'rat'){ 
$('#rat').show();
}
if(this.value == 'cat'){ 
$('#cat').show();
}
}
```

css :

```
 input {
display:'block'
}
```

also hide it in init if you need

Comment: i am not able to understand can u please edit my code and show me if is it possible ??